# Meteor local vs. admin databases

Tags: meteor

Where can I find documentation about the difference between Meteor's local and admin DB? I am trying to insert an object into an existing collection from a python script, but I am unsure whether I should insert into `local` db or `admin` db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB docs have this information

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/local-database/

and

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/

Are probably good places to start.

Comment: When I do `Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");` to which db is this information stored?

Comment: If you insert any data into the `Mongo.Collection` it will automatically create a new db called `courses`.

Comment: but isn't that a collection, not db?

Comment: Woops, yes you are correct. It will create a collection called `courses` in the `meteor` db